# jQuery fill circle based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am having trouble creating a circle and animatiing a fill effect based on a value.

Currently I have a HTML5 progress bar and it prgresses based on a score value

I declare it as such:

```
var bar = document.getElementById('progBar'),
```

Then within a function I set it accordingly based on the CurrentScore variable:

```
bar.value = CurrentScore;
```

Rather than use a prgress bar I would like to use a circle. The problem is that every plugin i have tried to use will not let you change the value dynamically. It will only set when page loads. My latest failed attempt was through the use of this plugin that will only run on load so therefore it does not work within my function.

Does anybody know how to fill a circle dynamically based on a changing value?

This plugin requires to run onload and can not be used inside a function.
DEMO [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/LstNS/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRy this http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/8/

```
 function setpb(){
   //  alert("in set");

 $('#rotator').rotator({
        starting: $("#startval").val(),
        ending: $("#endval").val(),
        lineWidth: 10
    })
  //   alert("completed");
 }
```

You can use dynamic values instead of textboxes. Use 0 in one increase in sencond and press ok for testing this

Comment: Is there a way to modify the plugin so that the top value is one thousand? thanks.

Comment: TRy this http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/9/  use 0 to 200 or 0 - 500 also use percentage: false as option if you not want sow % as this migh look odd to have 1000%